# Correct usage of callbacks in cell

Tags: swift, uitableview

I usually prefere to use callbacks, and in this example wanted to know if I get everything correct

I have a tableView with custom cell, which has 2 buttons.

So I have 2 callbacks (blocks), and when user tap the buttons I fire them

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    cell.firstButtonAction = {
        print(indexPath,cell)
        print(self)
    }
    cell.secondButtonAction {
        print(indexPath,cell) 
        print(self)
    }
    return cell
}
```

So my question is because, by default, callbacks keep value's strong reference, should I use

> [weak self]

to avoid strong reference Cycles?

and same for

> indexPath,cell

if cells are reusable, is it correct to catch them here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, if `self` is going to be used in the closure add `[weak self]` or `[unowned self]` to avoid retain cycles.

   ```
   cell.firstButtonAction = { [weak self] in
   ```
2. No, captured local values like `indexPath` or `cell` don't cause retain cycles.

Comment: Thanks got it
Small question, just wanted to know if is there any case to use delegation instead of callbacks? because if I can capture local variables,it helps a lot to understand which item was tapped, and I dont need to send any tag or indentifier to understand which cell was tapped with delegation

Comment: Whenever you can use callbacks, do it. Delegate can be useful for target / action and for methods which are called to return something like the `NS/UITableView`  or `NS/UIViewController` delegate methods.